# Що означає слово "здибанка"?

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, розмовна-українська

У словнику SUM-20 таке означення цього слова:

> ЗДИ́БАНКА, и, ж., розм. Те саме, що зу́стріч 1, 2. Мамі своїй оповідав [Бумблякевич] .. і про знайомство в парку, і про театр, і про те, як домовився на наступну зустріч, і про всі подальші здибанки з докладними розмовами (Ю. Винничук); А село .. усе бачило, наївна дівчино, ще тоді, коли вперше до тебе прийшов на нічну здибанку чорнобровий кандидат в агрономи (С. Процюк); По поверненню [по поверненні] з реанімації у нього була остання здибанка з Соломією (Любко Дереш).

Отже здибанка — це зустріч. Проте і у наведених прикладах, і єдиний раз коли я чув це слово (у мультику "Тачки") — всі приклади демонструють лише значення "побачення".

Чи дійсно можна використовувати це слово у значенні "зустріч" не пов'язанному із "побаченням" — ділова зустріч, випадкова зустріч будь-з-ким на вулиці і т.і.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Здибанка* може використовуватись у таких значеннях:

- *побачення* без серйозних намірів, з метою початкового знайомства;
- для опису зустрічей, метою яких є *знайомство* людей між собою;
- для опису *неформальних* зустрічей. Наприклад, здибанкою можна назвати зустріч випускників або колег. В цьому значенні синонімом *здибанки* може бути слово *посиденьки*;
- в контексті випадкової зустрічі, наприклад, замість *зустрів старого друга* можна сказати *здибав старого друга*.

Відповідно, для бізнес зустрічей або для опису зустрічей людей, що будуть серйозні стосунки, слово *здибанка* не підходить.

Answer (score 7):

Там де виріс я, завжди використовували це слово як синонім до слова *зустріч*.

Але воно завжди мало жартівливо-зневажливий або молодіжний відтінок. Старші люди могли сказати: "молодь пішла на *здибанку*", але самі вони завжди ходили на *зустріч* або *збори*. Частіше вживалося у дієслівному варіанті - *здибатися*. Є також така приказка:

> Яке їхало, таке здибало.

яка теж завжди вживалася у зневажливому тоні, напр.: - "ти така нечепура і друг твій такий же". Хочу зауважити, що приказка сама по собі не має лише зневажливе значення.

Зараз, як я бачу *здибанка* та *здибатися* практично стали синонімами *зустрічі* та *зустрітися*.

Comment: там де виріс я спільнокорінне [надибати](http://sum.in.ua/s/nadybaty) - сленгово-суржикове, використовується як перехідне дієслово у літературному значенні неперехідного

Answer (score 3):

На Західній Україні часто чув "здибав з ..." знайомого. Тобто можна використовувати не в значенні побачення

Comment: Чи це є Ваш аргумент на користь того, що можна застосовувати це слово не в значенні [побачення](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Побачення) — чи ні? Поясніть, будь ласка. Якщо так, відредагуйте, будь ласка, Вашу відповідь, додавши це **явно**.

Comment: "здибав з кумом", наприклад, у значенні, що не мав зустрітися зним (тобто не побачення), та раптово зустрів.