# Переклад слова "networking"

Tags: переклад, from-english

В фейсбуку підняли тему [щодо слова networking](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1272175826151516/).

Як на мене, найближче по смисловому значенню - *"соціалізація"*, хоча це швидше синонім, аніж прямий переклад.

[Словотвір](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/netvorkynh) пропонує *"мережування"*. Але якесь воно кострубате.

Може, є кращі аналогії?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

На моє питанні в групі Український Переклад на ФБ цілком слушно зауважили, що "нетворкінг" уже ввійшов у комунікацію і доволі широко використовується. Так-то воно так, але оце -інгове закінчення особисто мене дуже бісить.

Тому я запропонував варіант *"нетворкування"* :) І милозвучніше, і по суті.  "нет+воркування", але українські голуби [туркають](http://sum.in.ua/s/turkaty)

Хоча, все ж, більше мені до вподоби *"суспілкування"*. Це слово поєднує в собі одразу кілька, на мій погляд, етимологічних моментів: спілкування (одна із підвалин нетворкингу), СУСПІЛьство, ну і су- на початку для мене звучить, як поєднання окремих частин (супідрядник тощо).

Answer (score 9):

Коротко:

**network: зв'язки

networking: (неформальне) спілкування, тусовка, бізнес-тусовка**

Наприклад:

> Let's go to the afterparty for the **networking**.
>
> Приходьте на вечірку для продовження **спілкування**.

---

Спочатку пропоную розібратись з тим, що означають терміни *networking* та *network*.

Визначення терміну в [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/networking.asp):

> Networking is a process that fosters the exchange of information and
>   ideas among individuals or groups that share common interests.
>   Networking may fall into one of two categories: social or business.
>
> Нетворкінг - це процес, який сприяє обміну інформації та ідей між
>   окремими людьми чи групами, що мають спільні інтереси. Нетворкінг може
>   бути **персональним** (соціальним) або **бізнесовим**.

Визначення *business networking* у [Вікіпедії](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_networking):

> Networking is a socioeconomic business activity by which
>   businesspeople and entrepreneurs meet to form business relationships,
>   share information and seek potential partners for ventures.
>
> Нетворкінг є соціально-економічною діловою активністю, за допомогою
>   якої бізнесмени і підприємці знайомляться один з одним задля
>   формування ділових відносин, обміну інформації та пошуку потенційних
>   партнерів.

Визначення *нетворкінгу* в Вікіпедії з описом локального контексту (наприклад, влаштувати дитину в дитсадок, що, очевидно, містить елементи *блату* та *кумівства* (я ще додам сюди термін *криша*), про які йде мова в [цій відповіді](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/460/326)):

> Нетворкінг (англ. networking) — соціальна і професійна діяльність,
>   спрямована на те, щоб за допомогою кола друзів і знайомих максимально
>   швидко і ефективно вирішувати складні життєві завдання і
>   бізнес-питання (приклад: знаходити клієнтів, наймати кращих
>   співробітників, залучати інвесторів). При цьому, в суті нетворкінгу
>   лежить вибудовування довірчих і довгострокових відносин з людьми і
>   взаємодопомога.

Така різниця в трактуванні нетворкінгу полягає в різниці бізнес-культур в пострадянських країнах (де розвинутий індивідуалізм і контрпродуктивна конкуренція) та американської, де бізнес будується на довірі та співпраці (*partnership*).

Тому, на мій погляд, найточніший відповідником *network* в українській мові є слово *зв'язки* (російською - *связи*):

> Связи решают всё.
>   Зв'язки вирішують все.

Тут потрібно зазначити, що в англійській мові *network* - однина, в той час як український відповідник вживається у множині. Це накладає певні нюанси при семантичному перекладі речень, що містять слово *network*. В українському контексті слово *зв'язки* вживаються при їх повній наявності або відсутності (*у нього є зв'язки / у нього немає зв'язків*). В той самий час, *network* передбачає *проміжний* стан, коли точно не відомо, чи існує підходяща людина, тому допускається його пошук (*I will search in my network*), а також припускає, що *розширення нетворку* (*extending network*) - потенційно бескінечний процес (на відміну від бінарної системи наявності чи відсутності зв'язків).

Тепер щодо *networking*, який є **процесом** встановлення зв'язків. Тут теж потрібно детальніше зупинитись на тому, де і як це відбувається. В пострадянських країнах бізнес-зустрічі зазвичай відбуваються за "зачиненими дверима", під час персональних зустрічей. Натомість в західній бізнес культурі першочергове знайомство, зазвичай, відбувається на публічних заходах (конференціях, форумах та **мітапах**). Лише зараз ця культура поступово приходить до нас.

Де зазвичай відбувається нетворкінг:

- на *networking afterparty* - вечірніх подіях з метою знайомства з учасниками конференції чи форуму після того, як основна програма (в більшості випадків, лекційна) закінчилась, і учасники можуть поспілкуватись в **неформальній обстановці**;
- на *networking preparty* - подіях, що відбуваються *до* основної програми з метою кращого розуміння аудиторії і *планування* активностей під час великої події (також *networking preparty* називають *welcome reception*);
- якщо пишуть *networking party*, то це означає, що подія не прив'язана до іншої події;
- на *мітапах* (термін пішов від назви сайту для організації такого роду подій - [meetup.com](http://meetup.com)), що поступово заміняє *networking party*. Формат мітапів (бізнес зустрічі загальною тривалістю 2-2,5 години, де спочатку - нетворкінг, потім по 10-20 хвилин одна або дві перезентації, потім знову нетворкінг) не розповсюджений в Україні, проте іноді такі події все ж відбуваються серед ІТ спеціалістів, що привносять елементи західної бізнес-культури в Україну).

Хотів написати, що мітап схожий на [здибанку](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/228/326) або *посиденьки*, але є ключова відмінність - *здибанка* і *посиденьки*, зазвичай, проходять в сидячому форматі, а *мітапи* - лише стоячи.

Різновидом networking є *speed dating* - *швидкі знайомства*, коли незнайомі люди сідають за одним столом і у них є обмежена кількість часу (зазвичай до 3 хвилини) для того, щоб розповісти про себе, свій досвід та кого вони шукають на цій зустрічі (партнера, менеджера продукту, розробника чи клієнтів).

---

*Мережування*, очевидно, є спробою перекладу *networking* в контексті *social networking*, тобто знайомства в соціальних мережах на кшталт Facebook або Twitter. Думаю, що такий варіант *може* бути використаний для визначення знайомства через соціальні мережі, де можна *зафрендити* (від англ. *to friend* - стати друзями в соціальній мережі) або *зафоловити* когось (від англ. to follow - слідувати за кимось).

Answer (score 2):

**Попередній аналіз проблеми**

[За посиланням](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/netvorkynh) у пості, на яке подане посилання <sub>(досить складна конструкція, егеж?)</sub> надано наступне значення англійського слова *networking*:

> Створення і підтримка мережі контактів для подальшої комунікації і просування якихось ідей, послуг, продуктів

**Осяяння плеканими джерелами**

*Напевно*, в силу деяких історичних причин *питоме слово* для позначення такого явища в українській мові вистраждано не було.

В українській мови існують як мінімум два слова, які описують схожі явища, але, в силу тих самих суто історичних причин, ці слова мають яскраві домішки негативного сенсу. Значення таких можна знайти у Академічному тлумачному словнику:

1. [*КУМІ́ВСТВО*](http://sum.in.ua/s/kumivstvo) у значенні:

> Потурання по службі своїм друзям або родичам на шкоду справі.

1. [*БЛАТ*](http://sum.in.ua/s/blat) зі значенням

> Знайомство, зв'язки і т. ін., що використовуються в особистих інтересах.

**Висновики**

*Кумівство* означає *networking* у поданому значенні + [*непотизм*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC)

*Блат* означає *networking* у поданому значенні + [*злочин*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD). Має ще більш виразний негативний відтінок, [тяжке сьогодення](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F) і, так би мовити, [сумнівне](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/10279) [походження](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82) для широкого використання і легкого прийняття у літературну мову в поданому сенсі:

> Сьогоднішнє значення слова «блат» — корисні зв'язки, знайомства, завдяки яким можна отримати які-небудь блага *в обхід загальноприйнятих правил і законів*, як правило, у збиток інтересам суспільства або держави. «По блату» — завдяки вигідному знайомству, через «потрібних»

Comment: Ні, це не зв'язано з непотизмом, блатом та кумівством. Приклад networking - ти працюєш у компанії, що продає певні продукти (чи послуги). Ти їдеш на конференцію, де ти займаєшся наступним:

* показуєш презентацію свого продукту
* дивишся презентації інших продуктів
* займаєшся networking - тобто просто спілкуєшся з потенційними клієнтами та партнерами у неформальній обстановці, з кимось знайомишся, з кимось ти вже знайомий, просто ділишся новинами - і особистими, і по роботі. Це більше схоже на профейсійну соціалізацію.

Comment: Це був один з прикладів networking. Інший приклад - через linkedin шукаєш людей, що цікавляться твоїм продуктом, або що можуть бути корисними в його просуванні. Знайомишся, спілкуєшся. Тут відсутній корупційний елемент, який є в кумовстві.

Comment: я все це чітко зазначив у своїй відповіді, що кумівство та блат - це специфічна мутація явища, назви якому можливо не зберіглося

Comment: @Chizh  гарне дослідження, але все ж треба для повноти відповіді запропонувати якийсь варіянт. *Братання* в цю схему не підходить? Чи мо' *кумпанійство* :)?

Comment: кумпель відпадає, бо має інакше ([companis](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kumpan)) від кума ([commater](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC#Etymology_1_2)) походження. Тобто між кумом та кумпелєм спільного - латинський перфікс у родоводі.

Comment: Мені подобається ваше дослідження і мутація має місце, проте networking є процесом набуття корисних зв'язків, кумовство і блат - їх використанням.