# Як назвати зустріч подружок, на яку не беруть хлопців/чоловіків?

Tags: фразеологізми, одним-словом, вибір-слова

У російській мові є слово "девичник", яке означає зустріч подружок нареченої перед весіллям. Але саме слово не має прив'язок до часу дня чи весільних традицій.

Пошук перекладу "девичник" на r2u.org.ua дає такі варіанти:

> діви́ч-ве́чір, вінкопле́тини, дру́жбини.

- Дівич-вечір - добре, що є про дівчат, тільки погано, що обов'язково виходить "вечір".
- Дружбини - не сказано, що можна лише дівчатам.
- Вінкоплетини - є прив'язка до традиції вінкоплетіння (може це і добре?), і знову не зрозуміло, чи можна приходити хлопцям, якщо вони теж хочуть плести вінки.

"Мальчишник" на тому самому сайті дає:

> парубочий вечір, (перед свадьбой) вечори́ни, підвесі́лок, дружби́ни

Знов "вечір", "весілля" і дружбини.

Чи є якесь інше слово, щоб описати неформальну зустріч подружок (upd: що не пов'язана з весіллям), на яку не пускають хлопців?

Comment: Фігурування «вечір» у «дівич-вечір» не слід сприймати буквально. [Випускний вечір](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Випускний_вечір) теж проходить не зовсім ввечері.

Comment: «Дівич-вечір» сприймається надто етнографічно. «Дівоча вечірка» звучить більш нейтрально.

Comment: Дівоча [здибанка](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/223/%D0%A9%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%94-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0)?

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko Як варіант підійде, бо саме слово "здибанка" мені дуже подобається, хоча це і не "одним-словом". :)

Comment: Тоді "дівич-здибанка" (одне слово - складний іменник), хоч у мене оце 'дівич' одразу асоціюється з дівич-вечором, і саме тим, що передує весіллю :)

Comment: Ще є варіант [посиденьки](http://sum.in.ua/s/posydenjky) (дівочі посиденьки, дівич-посиденьки), але, як на мене, йому бракує 'активності')

Answer (score 4):

Якщо ж узятись щодо *[дівич](http://sum.in.ua/s/divych)-вечір*, що й *[вечірка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0)*, то [значення](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53394/376646.html) часу дещо утратилось, оскільки немає точного перекладу іншого слова *[party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Party)*, лише дещо наближене, наприклад: *[гулянка](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghuljanka)*, тощо.

Причому, це англійське слово [також](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96) [вжилось](http://slovopedia.org.ua/39/53407/260865.html) у мову. Тому вже нікого не здивує [*дівич-паті*](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%22).

---

Оскільки ви не ставили мету, що тре відповісти тільки словом українського походження, то на цьому можна вже зупинитися, оскільки це слово підходить за іншими параметрами: не відноситься до часу, весілля й має чітко «дівочий напрям».

Але я хотів би розвинути свої особисті думки. Як на мене, є шанс на життя таким наступним словам: *дівич-час*, *дівичка*, *дівульба*. Доволі цікаво, що є село [Дівички́](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8).

---

Оскільки щодо парубків ви лише опосередковано згадали, тут немає потреби мати відповідь щодо них. Але ж знову... По-перше, я хотів би вас доповнити, що є ще варіант *холостяцька вечірка*.

Щодо своїх думок чи варіантів, то мені вже складніше тут. Найбільш вдалим хіба що буде *паруб-паті*.

Comment: Третя частина відповіді виглядає зовсім як оффтопік, бо автор прямо запитує про дівочу вечірку, куди **не** пускають хлопців. А у другій частині відповіді, назва села навряд чи походить від «дівочої вечірки».

Comment: @bytebuster, ну, прямо на запитання Follower відповів — тепер може висловити і додаткові особисті думки — чому б ні. (Крім того, мені здається, що це Ви трішки не спіймали хід його думок; адже автор запитання наводив приклади слів на позначення аналогічних чоловічих вечірок (куди, можливо, не пускають дівчат) — а Follower просто розширив його перелік.) [Дівичка](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=дівичка) AFAIK означає просто «діва»/«дівчин(к)а» (але теоретично слово може набрати нового значення).

Answer (score 3):

Трішки не зрозуміло - це слово взагалі не має бути пов'язане із весіллям? Бо якщо ми говоримо про "девишник", то саме "дівич-вечір" буде найкращим варіантом:

1. Його рекомендує вживати і сайт [мова ДНК](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/divuch-vechir), і [Олександр Авраменко](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJMg3SqTX5M), і [Російсько-український словник](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/11/53396/127887.html), і в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/divych-vechir) воно є.
2. Так само як і слово "[девишник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)" "дівич-вечір" означає певний обряд, який проводять перед днем весілля. І хоч зараз традиції плести вінки вже не є такою популярною, гадаю, що саме слово заслуговує на те, щоб його активно використовували. А саме слово "вечір" тут присутнє лише через те, що "дівич-вечеру" передували "[запросини](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=a0j9CQAAQBAJ&pg=PA45&dq=%22%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%96%D1%80%22&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3idaUi5bgAhWH3iwKHVXBDNkQ6AEIODAD#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%96%D1%80%22&f=false)", які відбувалися днем.

І знову ж повторюся, що "девишник" (так само як і "мальчишник") не може означати "**неформальну** зустріч подружок, на яку не пускають хлопців", бо саме значення:

"Передвесільний обряд, день перед весіллям"

Тобто воно все ж пов'язане із весіллям.

І тут же на російській Вікіпедії бачимо варіанти "девишник" у різних мов слов'янської групи. І серед українських зустрічаємо "**дівочі запоїни**". Звучить кумедно, але все ж із вечором не пов'язане. Також зустрічаємо такий варіант в книзі "[Етнокульткурні зв'язки українців та білорусів Полісся](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=IIjfAAAAMAAJ&q=%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8&dq=%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK9sX3jZbgAhUqhaYKHYzeD4gQ6AEIKDAA)". Та і в [словнику Грінченка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8) бачимо такий варіант.

Отож, якщо ви хочете перекласти "девишник", то використовуйте варіант "дівич-вечір". Однак, якщо ви не бажаєте прив'язувати подію до слова вечора (хоча в коментарях влучно підмітили, що "дівич-вечір" не обов'язково повинен відбуватися ввечері) то можете використати варіант "дівочі запоїни".

Comment: Так, зустріч не пов'язана з весіллям. Якби була пов'язана, то, звичайно, "дівич-вечір" був би традиційним варіантом.

Comment: Я маю на увазі, що "дівішнік", який ви наводите у запитанні також пов'язаний із весіллям. Тому не впевнений, що в рос. мові є слово яке б означало "неформальну зустріч подружок".

Comment: У сучасному мовленні є і "неформальна зустріч": https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/274409/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA , https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/107868/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA

Answer (score 0):

Дівич-вечір найкраще підходить. Це узвичаєна народна традиція. Думаю, не суттєво вечір чи не вечір. Якщо це народна мова, можна і самому скласти "дівич-день", наприклад.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, завжди додавайте поважні джерела, які підтверджують вашу думку. Відповіді, які базуються на «я думаю», є суб'єктивними, отримують мінуси і видаляються. Також, перегляньте [критерії](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/), за якими ми оцінюємо хороші дописи і відрізняємо їх від поганих.

Comment: Підтримую варіант «дівич-вечір». Фігурування в ньому слова «вечір» не слід сприймати буквально. [Випускний вечір](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Випускний_вечір) теж проходить зовсім не ввечері. (А рос. [утренник](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/утренник), якщо знаєте таке слово, не обов'язково вранці [хоча рос. «утро» = ранок].)

Comment: Ось тому мені і не подобаються (як назви подій) "вранішніки" з початком о 19:00 чи "вечори", що починаються зранку і закінчуються після обіду.